# What is the %U in `chromium %U` for inside chromium.desktop?

Tags: chrome, freedesktop

Is that specific for chromium, or does it have to do with the way unix/linux launches the command? What does it do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It indicates that `chromium` may be passed a list of URLs on its command line.  See the [`Exec` key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html) of the [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) for a description of the available codes and what they mean.

Comment: can you be more esoteric?