# What is this password prompt after logging in to Debian 9?

Tags: debian, login, password, prompt

Every time I restart the system and log in, a password prompt pops up:

[image: Password prompt]

In most cases, this happens as soon as I open Chromium (it actually seems to freeze up the browser), and usually clicking on "Cancel" re-opens the prompt several (3-5) more times, which is extremely annoying. What is causing this and how can I disable it? Is there any way to identify the process behind it, e.g. using `htop`?

Desktop environment is XFCE 4.

Comment: Hit continue without adding a password and it will stay away. If you do add a password you need to provide it when this pops up. This is the connecting between your password safe and software that is set for a password. Oh and the one this is likely about is your network connection ie. networkmanager. When you provide a password here no internet unless you provide a password.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this?

Answer from the manpages `man chromium`:

> ```
>   --password-store=<basic|gnome|kwallet>
>           Set  the  password  store to use.  The default is to automatically detect based on the desktop environment.
>
>       basic selects the built in, unencrypted password store.  
>       gnome  selects  Gnome  keyring.   
>       kwallet  selects (KDE) KWallet.  (Note that KWallet may not work reliably outside KDE.)
> ```

---

> How to disable it?

run chromium with: `--password-store=basic` :

```
chromium --password-store=basic
```

You can create and alias :

```
alias chromium='chromium /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop'
```

Then run: `chromium` from the terminal.

Also you can edit the chromium configuration file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop
```

Change the following line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium %U
```

to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium --password-store=basic %U
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have solved the issue. Is it possible to block Chromium from saving **any** password at all? Also, what is the purpose of **%U**?

Comment: @david https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55053/153195